# Cylindrical Coordinates: Can someone verify my answer?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, mathematical-physics, cylindrical-coordinates

**Question:** Consider the solid $V$ of unit density, where $V$ is the region inside the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4k^2$ and outside the cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = k^2$.

Using cylindrical coordinates, set up and calculate the moment of inertia of $V$ about the $z$-axis. Show all calculations.

**Answer:** 
I set up the integral as follows, $$I_z = \int_{0}^{2π}\int_{k}^{2k}\int_{-\sqrt{ 4k^2 -\rho^2}}^{\sqrt{ 4k^2 -\rho^2}}\rho^3dzd\rho d\phi$$

Solving this integral, I obtained,$$ I_z = \frac{44π\sqrt 3 k^5}{5} $$
I'm a bit dubious as to whether this is correct because when I'm hesitant when using the equation for moment of inertia.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This looks correct. If you want someone to check the individual steps, you should edit them into the equation. If there is some particular concern or doubt that makes you "hesitant," maybe you should make the question be about that. As it is, you don't seem to need any help.

Comment: My particular concern is whether to input in $k^2$ or $\rho^2$ for the $x^2 + y^2$ term in the initial moment of inertia integral.

Comment: You set this up so that $\rho$ is the coordinate for the distance from the $z$ axis. Therefore at any arbitrary point whose Cartesian coordinates are $(x,y,z),$ you have $x^2 + y^2 = \rho^2.$ On the other hand, $k$ is the radius of the cylinder, so $x^2 + y^2 = k^2$ only on the surface of the cylinder, not anywhere else in the volume between the cylinder and the sphere. So you made the correct choice by using $\rho^2.$